# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…521739130434781,NaNL60.739130434…". at platform-browser.js:1151

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I have to draw a line graph for a project. I based my graph on the example provided at https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-line-chart?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

i got the example to work and transformed my data to refelct the necessary interfaces. my data now looks like this:

```
[
{
    "name": "SEM+",
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "30",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "90",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "120",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "150",
            "value": 56.2
        },
        {
            "name": "180",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "210",
            "value": 2.5999999999999996
        },
        {
            "name": "240",
            "value": 1.4
        },
        {
            "name": "300",
            "value": 0.2
        },
        {
            "name": "360",
            "value": 3.5999999999999996
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "mean",
    "series": [
        [
            {
                "name": "30",
                "value": -0.1
            },
            {
                "name": "90",
                "value": -0.1
            },
            {
                "name": "120",
                "value": -0.1
            },
            {
                "name": "150",
                "value": 28
            },
            {
                "name": "180",
                "value": -0.1
            },
            {
                "name": "210",
                "value": 1.2
            },
            {
                "name": "240",
                "value": 0.7
            },
            {
                "name": "300",
                "value": 0.1
            },
            {
                "name": "360",
                "value": 1.7
            }
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "name": "SEM-",
    "series": [
        [
            {
                "name": "30",
                "value": -0.2
            },
            {
                "name": "90",
                "value": -0.2
            },
            {
                "name": "120",
                "value": -0.2
            },
            {
                "name": "150",
                "value": -0.1999999999999993
            },
            {
                "name": "180",
                "value": -0.2
            },
            {
                "name": "210",
                "value": -0.19999999999999996
            },
            {
                "name": "240",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "300",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "360",
                "value": -0.19999999999999996
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

]

fields in my component:

```
 // data for the graph
  @Input() timeData: TimeData[];
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input('activeSubstance') yAxisLabel;
  transformedData: any[];
  // options
  xAxisLabel = 'time (min)';
  legend = true;
  xAxis = true;
  yAxis = true;
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  timeline = true;
  dimensions: any[] = [700, 300];
  ticks: any[] = [30, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 300, 360];

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#E44D25', '#CFC0BB', '#7aa3e5', '#a8385d', '#aae3f5']
  };
```

html:

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
  [view]="dimensions"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  [legend]="legend"
  [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
  [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
  [xAxis]="xAxis"
  [yAxis]="yAxis"
  [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
  [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
  [results]="transformedData"
  [xAxisTicks]="ticks">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

first of all, i had to manually input the xAxisTicks since the ngx chart didn't recognize them. with that i got the tick contructor error to disappear.

adding the [timeline] attribute throws more error but i think i won't need that.

however, the errors that i am getting with the data i put in are:

Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…521739130434781,NaNL60.739130434…". at platform-browser.js:1151

and

Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…521739130434781,NaNL60.739130434…" at attrTween.js:5

with this configuration I now also get the same error with the testdata that previously worked. It does still draw the lines though, which it does not for my data.

i also tried other browsers, the issue persists....

edit: posting the full code

component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TimeData} from '../../../models/TimeData';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-graph',
  templateUrl: './line-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-graph.component.scss']
})
export class LineGraphComponent implements OnInit {

  data = [
    {
      'name': 'Germany',
      'series': [
        {
          'name': '1990',
          'value': 62000000
        },
        {
          'name': '2010',
          'value': 73000000
        },
        {
          'name': '2011',
          'value': 89400000
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      'name': 'USA',
      'series': [
        {
          'name': '1990',
          'value': 250000000
        },
        {
          'name': '2010',
          'value': 309000000
        },
        {
          'name': '2011',
          'value': 311000000
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      'name': 'France',
      'series': [
        {
          'name': '1990',
          'value': 58000000
        },
        {
          'name': '2010',
          'value': 50000020
        },
        {
          'name': '2011',
          'value': 58000000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'name': 'UK',
      'series': [
        {
          'name': '1990',
          'value': 57000000
        },
        {
          'name': '2010',
          'value': 62000000
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  // data for the graph
  @Input() timeData: TimeData[];
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input('activeSubstance') yAxisLabel;
  transformedData: any[];
  // options
  xAxisLabel = 'time (min)';
  legend = true;
  xAxis = true;
  yAxis = true;
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  timeline = true;
  dimensions: any[] = [700, 300];
  ticks: any[] = [30, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 300, 360];

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#E44D25', '#CFC0BB', '#7aa3e5', '#a8385d', '#aae3f5']
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.colorScheme = {domain: ['#868686', this.color, '#868686']};
    this.transformedData = this.createTransfromedData();
    console.log(this.transformedData);
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  createTransfromedData() {
    const data = [];
    data.push({name: 'SEM+', series: [this.makeSeries('SEM+')]});
    data.push({name: 'mean', series: [this.makeSeries('mean')]});
    data.push({name: 'SEM-', series: [this.makeSeries('SEM-')]});
    return data;
  }

  makeSeries(funcName: string) {
    const seriesData = [];
    for (const stamp of this.timeData) {
      if (parseFloat(stamp.data.SEM)) {
        if (parseFloat(stamp.data.MEAN)) {
          if (funcName === 'SEM+') {
            seriesData.push(
              {
                name: stamp.time.toString(),
                value: parseFloat(stamp.data.MEAN) + parseFloat(stamp.data.SEM)
              });
          }
          if (funcName === 'mean') {
            seriesData.push(
              {
                name: stamp.time.toString(),
                value: parseFloat(stamp.data.MEAN)
              });
          }
          if (funcName === 'SEM-') {
            seriesData.push(
              {
                name: stamp.time.toString(),
                value: parseFloat(stamp.data.MEAN) - parseFloat(stamp.data.SEM)
              });
          }

        }
      }
    }
    return seriesData;
  }
}
```

html code is just the one i posted above

The component is called within another component like so:

```
<app-line-graph [timeData]="report.experiments[0].timeData" 
                [activeSubstance]="report.activeSubstance" 
                [color]="experimentColors[0]">
</app-line-graph>
```

Comment: What is your full code, and on what line is the error being generated?

Comment: I added the full code that I'm using, the error seems to occur at platform-browser.js:1151

Comment: I did finally find it! i had [] brakcets around my series data which caused it. thank you for making me review my code! :P